# How to add 2 fragments dynamically in a single layout?

Tags: android, dynamic

I want to add 2 fragments in a single layout like this:

[image: Two Fragments]

I was able to do it using static fragment method but not able to do it dynamically. I want to target API 14 and above.

Here is the code:

1. activity_main.xml:

```js
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/new_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

2. fragment1.xml:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fragment first"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

3. fragment2.xml:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#0000ff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fragment second"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

4. fragment1.java:

```js
package org.hinduismfacts.www.dynamicfragment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Rahul on 07-08-2017.
 */

public class fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,container, false);
    }

}
```

5. fragment2.java:

```js
package org.hinduismfacts.www.dynamicfragment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Rahul on 07-08-2017.
 */

public class fragment2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,container, false);
    }

}
```

6. MainActivity.java:

```js
package org.hinduismfacts.www.dynamicfragment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
// Create new fragment and transaction
        Fragment newFragment = new fragment1();
        Fragment myFragment = new fragment2();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
        transaction.add(R.id.new_placeholder, newFragment);
        transaction.add(R.id.my_placeholder, myFragment);

        transaction.commit();

    }
}
```

In the output I am getting only first fragment displayed. The second fragment is not getting added. Output:

[image: Output]

Can you please tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: First image shows horizontal orientation. Code says vertical orientation. Please be clear with your question

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. Actually, I had copied that from a website and as I am new to Android, I thought that was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please added `android:layout_weight="1"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/new_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need layout weight `android:layout_weight` for both your frame layout
try below XML changes

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/new_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: first, check the image in above question he wants to divide with width

Comment: Don't you think, horizontal orientation on a mobile device will be like awkward??? & moreover he has provided orientation as vertical

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your activity_main.xml.
Use `android:layout_weight="1"` for each of your fragments container to show both of them on the screen.

Also `fill_parent` is deprecated. Consider using `match_parent` instead